# Lattice plot with both a second x- and a second y-axis?

Tags: r, lattice

I would like to add a 2nd y-axis (right) and a 2nd x-axis (top) to the following (lattice) levelplot. These axes should only indicate certain rows and columns (no labels) and thus mimick base-graphics' rug function. How can this be done?

```
library(lattice)
library(latticeExtra)

## Generate a correlation matrix
d <- 50
L <- diag(1:d)
set.seed(271)
L[lower.tri(L)] <- runif(choose(d,2))
Sigma <- L %*% t(L)
P <- cor(Sigma)

## Panel function
my_panel <- function(...) {
    panel.levelplot(...)
    panel.abline(h = (1:4)*10, v = (1:4)*10, lty = 2)
    panel.axis(side = "top", at = (1:50)-0.5, draw.labels = FALSE) # maybe a panel axis could do it? why not centered?
}

## Plot
obj1 <- levelplot(P, xlab = "Column", ylab = "Row",
                  col.regions = grey(c(seq(1, 0, length.out = 600))),
                  panel = my_panel)
obj2 <- xyplot(NA~NA, ylim = c(0, 50),
               scales = list(x = list(at = (1:50)-0.5, labels = rep("", 50)),
                             y = list(at = (1:50)-0.5, labels = rep("", 50))))
doubleYScale(obj1, obj2, use.style = FALSE) # idea based on latticeExtra; only gives a 2nd y-axis, though
```

Comment: Can you make it more clear what the desired output is? Perhaps create a sketch to show what you are trying to create? Are the second axes supposed to have different scales? Are you just trying to label things?

Comment: I'm trying to indicate certain rows and columns in block matrices when plotting correlation matrices. The blocks correspond to industry sectors and subsectors of the data. The above approach via panel.abline() works well for sectors, but the subsectors are just too many. Similar to rug(), I want to indicate the rows and columns of the subsectors outside at the top and the right (2ndary axes).

Comment: BTW, there is a `panel.rug`, but it does not plot the rugs on the outside of the plot region.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were onto a good idea with `panel.rug()`, but were stymied by **lattice**'s default clipping of its plotting to the panel's interior. To get around that, you can turn off clipping via the `par.settings=` argument. If you want to suppress the plotting of default axis tick marks on the right and top panel borders, you can do so using the `tck=` argument, as shown below.

```
my_panel <- function(...) {
    panel.levelplot(...)
    panel.abline(h = (1:4)*10, v = (1:4)*10, lty = 2)
    ## Have panel.rug print tick marks starting at 1 npc (edge of panel)
    ## and extending to 1.02 npc (slightly outside of panel). (See ?unit)
    panel.rug(x = (1:51)-0.5, y = (1:51)-0.5, 
              start = 1, end = 1.02,
              col="black")
}

levelplot(P, xlab = "Column", ylab = "Row",
          col.regions = grey(c(seq(1, 0, length.out = 600))),
          ## Suppress default scales on right and top sides, by setting their
          ## tick lengths to zero 
          scales = list(tck=c(1,0)),
          ## Turn off clipping, so that panel.rug can plot outside of the panel
          par.settings = list(clip = list(panel = "off")),          
          panel = my_panel)
```

[image]